# When to use <StaticQuery /> vs page query in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

As I understand in Gatsby, a page query would be made at the parent level and would be passed down as props to the children components. And a `<StatiQuery />` or the `useStaticQuery` hook when you are inside a component and want to obtain some data to pass into it. What is the best practice and when should I use one over another?

I'm guessing this comes down to React itself and if for example, we have components that need data at a deep level we would use `Context` and pass that down so you do not have to pass down props at deeper levels. Is it the same as this? Also if anyone has any patterns they use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually decide where to put my data in Gatsby by answering this question. Let's assume we're making an ecommerce store:

Do I have to read/write the data often?

1. Yes (i.e. adding/updating cart items): use Context
2. No, but the data should be accessed across the whole site (i.e. list of products for the search bar): use sourceNodes, and get the data via useStaticQuery
   https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#sourceNodes
3. No, but the data should be rendered to a page (i.e. product page): use createPages and pageContext then pass the necessary data to the created page
   https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages

I think the important thing here is, if you put your data source in gatsby-node, you don't expect it to update very often because you need to re-build whenever you need to update the data. Although, there can be workarounds like triggering a rebuild if you update the data.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you I will look into these resources as you mentioned!